# How to make GET request inside a GET request in NodeJS using Express

Tags: node.js, facebook, express

Basically, I'm trying to get Access Token from Facebook in my callBack GET method. Below is my code.

`getAccessToken` is not called at all. What's the right way to implement it?

```
app.get('/fbcallback', function(req, res) {


  var code = req.query.code;

  var getAccessToken =  'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/oauth/access_token?'+
   'client_id='+client_id+
   '&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+
   '&client_secret='+client_secret+
   '&code='+code;


   app.use(getAccessToken, function(req, res) {

        console.log('Token Call');

   });


});
```

Comment: try to get params from body like req.body.code

Comment: show what errors you are getting in console

Comment: this looks weird...why use app.use in app.get? you should take a look at the docs: http://expressjs.com/de/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: You should not use app.use inside get the call. It's for middlewares

Comment: Maybe you can try using the `request` module and act as an HTTP client instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `app.use` inside get the call.

You must be trying to do something like below. Inside get call make another get call for getting token.

```
var request = require('request');

app.get('/fbcallback', function (req, res) {
    var code = req.query.code;
    var getAccessToken = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/oauth/access_token?' +
        'client_id=' + client_id +
        '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri +
        '&client_secret=' + client_secret +
        '&code=' + code;

    request(getAccessToken, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    });
});
```